# C'est quoi l'effet quand l'enchaînement crée des syllables ouvertes ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, voyelles

(Pour cette question, je définis une syllabe ouverte comme une syllabe qui se termine avec une voyelle [prononcée] ou avec le phonème /z/, ce qui n'est pas une bonne définition pour la linguistique mondiale mais qui rend beaucoup plus facile la discussion qui suit. Par exemple: « chaud » et « chose » sont des mots avec une syllabe ouverte, « chaude » est un mot avec une syllabe fermée.)

Il y a (au moins) trois paires de phonèmes français qui exhibent une « allophonie partielle » selon l'ouverture de la syllabe, que l'on peut résumer comme « voyelles ouvertes dans des syllabes fermées » et vice-versa.

- /ø/, /œ/ : il n'y a qu'une seule paire minimale, « jeune » /ʒœn/ et « jeûne » /ʒøn/, et j'ai lu qu'il y a des gens qui disent « jeûne » comme « jeune ». Sauf *jeûne*, ces voyelles suivent la règle.
- /o/, /ɔ/ : on trouve des exceptions : si on écrit « au » ou « ô » on dit /o/, même dans des syllabes ouvertes. Mais la plupart suivent la règle, et je pense qu'il y a des parleurs qui ne font pas la distinction entre « côté » et « coter », par exemple.
- /e/, /ɛ/ : il y a beaucoup de paires minimales, mais néanmoins on trouve que la plupart suivent la règle.

Ma question, c'est : on sait que l'effet d'enchaînement peut changer la structure des syllabes selon la contexte, et est-ce qu'on change la qualité de les voyelles quand on fait ça ? Par exemple:

> Elle est jeune. /ɛ.le.ʒœn/
>
> Elle est jeune et grande. /ɛ.le.ʒœ.ne.ɡʁɑ̃d/

L'apparition du mot « et » dans la deuxième phrase change la syllabe de *jeune*, elle est maintenant ouverte et pas fermée.

Est-ce qu'on change aussi la qualité de la voyelle /ɛ.le.ʒø.ne.ɡʁɑ̃d/ ou est-ce qu'on ne fait pas ça (et donc on a une exception systématique à la règle.)

---

I am asking this question in both French and English in case I made a mistake above. (For this question, I define a syllable to be open if it ends in a vowel (spoken) or the phoneme /z/ — this isn't a good definition for the phonology of world languages, but it makes the following discussion easier. For example, "chaud" and "chose" are open syllables; "chaude" is not.)

There are (at least) three pairs of phonemes in French that exhibit a sort of partial allophony depending on whether the syllable is open or not. The rule can be summarized as "the open vowel occurs in closed syllables, and the closed vowel occurs in open syllables."

- /ø/, /œ/: There is only one minimal pair, "jeune" /ʒœn/ and "jeûne" /ʒøn/, and I've read that many do not even make the distinction. The word *jeûne* (and its relatives) are the only words where the vowel /ø/ occurs in a closed syllable.
- /o/, /ɔ/ : now there are more exceptions. Whenever we write "au" or "ô" we say /o/, even in open syllables. (Although again I think there are some native speakers who do not make this distinction, so that these sounds are allophones.
- /e/, /ɛ/ : for this one there are many exceptions.

My question is the following. We know that "enchaînement" can change the syllabification of a sentence. For instance,

> Elle est jeune. /ɛ.le.ʒœn/
>
> Elle est jeune et grande. /ɛ.le.ʒœ.ne.ɡʁɑ̃d/

The appearance of "et" in the second sentence makes the vowel of the word *jeune* occur in an open syllable, whereas when we say *jeune* in isolation it is in a closed syllable.
So, do we change the quality of the vowel to a closed vowel? i.e. do we say /ɛ.le.ʒø.ne.ɡʁɑ̃d/ ? Or do we leave the vowel alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La règle pour /o/~/ɔ/ n'est pas parfaite: on dit bien *hôtel* avec /o/ mais *hôpital* avec /ɔ/ (c'est un mot qui aurait gagné à être corrigé avec la réforme de 1990), et l'accent québécois de l'ouest dit généralement *poteau* avec deux /o/.

Je crois que normalement on ne modifie pas la prononciation de [o~ɔ],(1) mais on le fait généralement dans le cas de [e~ɛ] et [ø~œ], avec quelques exceptions:

- Bien entendu, on ne le fera pas dans le cas d'une paire minimale, donc la voyelle demeure /ø/ dans ton exemple.
- Certaines consonnes, notamment /z/, provoquent la conversion de la voyelle précédente en sa version longue/accentuée donc on dit /ø/ dans la finale *-euse* (et /o/ dans des mots comme *roseraie*, alors que *rosserais* prend un /ɔ/).
- Certains mots comme *médecin* et *événement* admettent les deux prononciation, d'où l'orthographe alternative dans le cas de *évènement*. Je ne suis pas certain de la raison phonologique pour *médecin*, mais dans le cas d'*événement*, c'est un cas d'[harmonie vocalique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonie_vocalique) (que l'on ne retrouve pas dans *avènement*, qui ne prend donc que l'accent grave)

(1)Je parle ici du français relativement standard. Si je me rappelle bien, les accents du sud de la France, notamment, ne distinguent *aucune* de ces paires de voyelles.

Comment: On distingue dans le midi, mais subtil. Des réf. pour le français méridional: [ici pour les tableaux](http://research.jyu.fi/pisantorni/phon/62.html), [ici une toute petite annalyse](http://www.sfu.ca/fren270/phonologie/page4_4.html) et [ici un travail conséquent avec bibliogrpahie](http://books.google.fr/books?id=2t9OKcDuqfgC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=les+voyelles+dans+le+fran%C3%A7ais+m%C3%A9ridional&source=bl&ots=fMq9glDjVq&sig=tWy5pTvpysqbCVKZ3ygcvvQeelk&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=VXDTU6GOHKqo0QWv54DgDA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=les%20voyelles%20dans%20le%20fran%C3%A7ais%20m%C3%A9ridional&f=false)

Comment: Pour résumer, dans le sud, ce n'est pas qu'il n'y a pas de distinction, c'est que tout est régulier. Les voyelles en fin de syllabes sont fermées, les autres sont ouvertes.

Comment: Donc ce sont des allophones, ce qui implique par définition qu'il n'y a pas de distinction (l'anglais a beau employer /p/ et /ph/, l'anglophone moyen ne peut pas les distinguer/prononcer naturellement en chinois).