# Phonologie vs phonétique : /ʁɔz/ vs [ʁoz]

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, voyelles

Wikipédia indique [ici](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_international#Quantit.C3.A9_.28allongement_ou_amu.C3.AFssement.29) que le mot « rose » est noté phonologiquement /ʁɔz/. Le Wiktionnaire semble en désaccord [ici](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rose). Est-ce une erreur de Wikipédia ? Sinon, pouvez-vous expliquer pourquoi la représentation phonologique réalisée par [ʁoz] n'est pas /ʁoz/.

Comment: Pour moi, il s'agit d'une erreur dans wikipédia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour un locuteur donné, la séquence *ros* est toujours prononcée de la même façon, soit [ʁoz], soit [ʁɔz]. Sachant cela, il n'y a aucune raison de chercher la phonétique d'une telle syllabe dans un dictionnaire car elle ne contient pas d'information.

La seule chose à retenir, c'est que dans les régions ou il y a un véritable choix entre /o/ et /ɔ/, c'est /o/ qui est utilisé entre /ʁ/ et /z/ dans une même syllabe. En particulier pour cette raison il est probablement préférable d'utiliser /ʁoz/ dans la représentation phonologique des dictionnaires. Il est cependant difficile de mettre tout le monde d'accord sur la représentation à employer.

Le problème vient du fait que dans certaines régions le choix entre /o/ et /ɔ/ n'existe pas vraiment, il n'est dépendant que du contexte syllabique ; la réalisation [o] est systématiquement utilisée en fin de syllabe et [ɔ] en milieu de syllabe. Les mots français ont [une tendance générale à suivre ce schéma](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11433/cest-quoi-leffet-quand-lencha%c3%aenement-cr%c3%a9e-des-syllables-ouvertes) et dans ces régions la séquence *ros* n'y échappe pas. Les locuteurs en question peuvent donc avoir tendance à utiliser la notation phonologique /ʁɔz/, ce qui a probablement provoqué la différence de point de vue entre le Wiktionnaire et Wikipédia.

Comment: Quand on utilise avec /ɔ/, est-ce que ça allonge le /z/ et est-ce qu'il y a une "variante" où la prononciation du e final est très claire, un peu comme [ceci](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=%22rozz%20e%22) ? Merci.

Comment: @Amphiteóth: Pour la longueur du /z/, rien de perceptible à cause du /ɔ/. Quand au *e* final, cf [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11445). Note que ce léger *e* final ne change pas l'autre voyelle, « rose » reste en vérité une seule syllabe (sauf en poésie). Par comparaison « rosé » a clairement deux syllabes et est donc prononcé [ʁo.ze] par tout le monde.